# Want to retrieve results on a particular partition key structure?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**My usecase**

I have a table name `Test` with partition key as `userId` and sort key as `campaignId`. My table looks like this

```
"userId (S)","noteId (S)","BName (S)","BValue (S)"
"123_x","123","hi","no"
"123_x","213","how","yes"
"123_x","321","are","yes"
"456_y","456","you","yes"
"456_y","546","i","yes"
"456_y","654","have","yes
```

Now i am trying to retrieve the items that are contains partition key `x`. For this i had used the below node.js code

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
 region: "ap-south-1",
 endpoint: "http://dynamodb.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com"
});

var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

var params = {
    TableName : "Test",
    ProjectionExpression:"userId,BName,BValue",
    KeyConditionExpression: "contains(#userId,:userid)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#userId": "userId"
        },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":userid": "x"
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Query succeeded.");
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
        });
    }
});
```

I am getting error like this:

```
Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "Invalid operator used in KeyConditionExpression: contains",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2018-08-23T17:59:01.094Z",
  "requestId": "O6PL6NSE1BR7QLGA4U1SOIKGJ7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,
  "retryDelay": 34.77326742946143
}
```

It seems i cant use contains in keycondition expressions. What is the workaround for this ?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. You must always specify the exact partition key when performing a DynamoDB query. Without redesigning your table your only option is to perform a scan and use a filter expression on the userId.

To avoid the expense of a table scan, you could add a field on your table named something like "userId_suffix" and populate it with the "x" and "y" type values from your example. Then you would create a global secondary index on "userId_suffix" and query for "x" on that.